# PHP - if statment inside echo with checkbox

Tags: php, if-statement, checkbox, echo

I need some help to resolve my issue. I did several investigations without any success. I have a table with a IsContrib column which is BOOLEAN. I want to display this column with my checkbox. If IsContrib=1 ==> checked else IsContrib=0 unchecked.

Here, how I did, but I get an error saying: `syntax error, unexpected ';'`

I trid to do like so:

```
echo "...
<td>&nbsp;<input name='checkboxNContrib[]' type='checkbox' id='checkboxNContrib[]' ".$rowNContribRunDis["IsNContrib"]==TRUE ? "checked='checked'"." value='".$rowNContribRunDis["IdVariantNContrib"]."'/>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
```

Here the whole echo:

```
    while($rowNContribRunDis = mysqli_fetch_assoc($PerformNContribSELECT)){
    $id = $rowNContribRunDis["IdVariantNContrib"];

    echo "<tr>
<td>&nbsp;".$rowNContribRunDis["ID"]."&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;".$rowNContribRunDis["Reference"]."&nbsp;</td>
<td><textarea name='ResultHRM[$id]' id='ResultHRM[]' cols='30' rows='1'>".$rowNContribRunDis['ResultHRM']."</textarea></td>
<td><textarea name='Commentaires[$id]' id='Commentaires[]' cols='60' rows='1'>".$rowNContribRunDis['Commentaires']."</textarea></td>
<td>&nbsp;<input name='checkboxNContrib[]' type='checkbox' id='checkboxNContrib[]' ".$rowNContribRunDis["IsNContrib"]==TRUE ? "checked='checked'"." value='".$rowNContribRunDis["IdVariantNContrib"]."'/>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
```

Comment: Get rid of mixing up markup and logic

Comment: Hi bub, can you develop more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty ugly and you should rewrite it!
Using ternary operator `?:` in string concatenation `"" . ""` you should use brackets, for eg. `"..." . (true ? "yes" : "no") . "..."` and also use lower string for `true` and `false`.

```
echo "<tr>
<td>&nbsp;" . $rowNContribRunDis["ID"] . "&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;" . $rowNContribRunDis["Reference"] . "&nbsp;</td>
<td><textarea name='ResultHRM[$id]' id='ResultHRM[]' cols='30' rows='1'>" . $rowNContribRunDis['ResultHRM'] . "</textarea></td>
<td><textarea name='Commentaires[$id]' id='Commentaires[]' cols='60' rows='1'>" . $rowNContribRunDis['Commentaires'] . "</textarea></td>
<td>&nbsp;<input name='checkboxNContrib[]' type='checkbox' id='checkboxNContrib[]' " . ($rowNContribRunDis["IsNContrib"] == true ? "checked='checked'" : "") . " value='" . $rowNContribRunDis["IdVariantNContrib"] . "'/>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

add colon(:)

```
".($rowNContribRunDis["IsNContrib"]==TRUE ? "checked='checked'" : "")."
```

Answer (score 0):

Mix HTML and PHP bad idea.

I see problem. Problem is with short if statement, tray placed within brackets example:

```
echo "Lorum ipsum" .($some == true ? 'yes' : '') . "adasda";
```

And always must be else statement

Comment: Not entirely true in regards of the else, you can do `$var1 = $var2 ?: 'Default';` although that will generate a notice if the `$var2` isn't set.